# Photoswipe / Use Close Button as History Back Button

Tags: javascript, gallery, history, back, photoswipe

I am not a good Javascript Programmer and so im coming to this question. I am using Photoswipe for some galleries in a project. Some galleries i dont use the thumbnail preview im opening them directly. Now, when i click the close button the image disappears and you can see just a blank page. 
Now i want to use the close button as a back in history function. I am using jquery and the photoswipe plugin, no jquery mobile or sansa touch.

Thanks for your help
Michael

Comment: post what have u tried,code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following to the button:

```
onclick="history.go(-1)
```

Now your button will look something like

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)">Close</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your custom script.js

```
var options = {
                ...,
                history: false,
                ...
};
```

And then initialize the gallery

```
var gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
gallery.init();
```